# How to buy the right collection if I'd like to have the whole Sandman series?

Tags: the-sandman

There are so many "Sandman" collections on Amazon. How could I know the right collection to buy if I'd like to have the whole series? What are the full contents of the series?
ps. with the same content, I'd prefer a more affordable set.

Comment: Shopping questions are off-topic I'm afraid, especially when the answer is trivially simple to find on the likes of [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/Sandman-Slipcase-Set-Neil-Gaiman/dp/1401238637)

Comment: @Valorum Funny, I have all the Sandman (umm.. I think - now I'm not so sure) and the product list on Amazon confuses me. Still, the question is off-topic.

Comment: BTW I recommend editing your question to ask which stories you need to get if you want to have the whole Sandman collection. Asking for a specific product recommendation is off-topic.

Comment: @ToddWilcox thank you for the reply. I've updated the question focusing on the content of the series.

Comment: I'm not aware of the exact sales items on Amazon and the likes, but I'd strongly recommend to go for the trade paperbacks. They should be affordable (especially if you don't buy all 10 at once), and they contain all the stories (75 issues + the special issue "Tale of Orpheus") in the order they should be read, i.e. the in-universe chronological order (more or less). Go for the 2010 or 2011 printing. _Absolute Sandman_ is the same thing, only it's 5 bricks ~2 kg each with giant pages and some non-essential content in the end (like introductions and scripts).

Comment: Everything that is not in the 76 issues should be read after the series. This goes for _Overture_ (especially _Overture_!), _Endless Nights_, _Death_ spin-offs, and various _Sandman Presents_ spinoffs (including Mike Carey's _Lucifer_). _The Dream Hunters_ takes place before the main narration of the series, and doesn't reference anything from it, but I'd still read it afterwards.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sandman_(Vertigo) has got plenty of info.

Comment: Given the publication history of _The Lord of the Rings_, questions about authors' preferred editions should be on topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Telling you what to buy would be off-topic, but I can tell you what stories make up the original run of *The Sandman*:

1. Vol 1. Preludes and Nocturnes
2. Vol 2. The Doll's House
3. Vol 3. Dream Country
4. Vol 4. Season of Mists
5. Vol 5. A Game of You
6. Vol 6. Fables and Reflections
7. Vol 7. Brief Lives
8. Vol 8. World's End
9. Vol 9. The Kindly Ones
10. Vol 10. The Wake

Any collection that includes all of those will have all of the original *Sandman* stories. It looks like *The Sandman: Overture* is a more recent prequel and *The Sandman: Endless Nights*, a related story, are graphic novels that you might want to have also.

Finally, there was a brief spin-off that was pretty good that came in two books: *Death: The High Cost of Living* and *Death: The Time of Your Life*, which are also confusingly available in collected forms with other material that is sometimes also included in other volumes mentioned above.

So it **is** a bit of a mess, but if you figure out how to get the ten volumes listed above, you'll have a great, epic story of Morpheus that is really what started the whole thing.

Comment: There is also the made-up Japanese folk tale, *The dream hunters*.

Comment: What's more confusing, there's the novella _The Dream Hunters_, with illustrations by Yoshitaka Amano, and there's the comic adaptation by P. Craig Russell. Both worth a read.